# Ubuntu (20.04LTS) update breaks Bluetooth connection

Tags: networking, updates, bluetooth, bluez

I'm working with PyBluez, and after the recent Ubuntu update, I could not establish (low-energy) connection between my Bluetooth adapters anymore.

Here is the update log:

```
Start-Date: 2022-07-06  15:28:01
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.88'
Upgrade: libqmi-proxy:amd64 (1.28.6-1~20.04.1, 1.30.4-1~ubuntu20.04.1), gnupg-utils:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), gpg-wks-client:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), openssl:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.15, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16), gnupg-l10n:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), update-notifier-common:amd64 (3.192.30.10, 3.192.30.11), azure-cli:amd64 (2.37.0-1~focal, 2.38.0-1~focal), snapd:amd64 (2.54.3+20.04.1ubuntu0.3, 2.55.5+20.04), ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64 (27.8~20.04.1, 27.9~20.04.1), libqmi-glib5:amd64 (1.28.6-1~20.04.1, 1.30.4-1~ubuntu20.04.1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (103.0.5060.53-1, 103.0.5060.114-1), gpg-wks-server:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), gpg:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), mainline:amd64 (1.0.15-0~202110201909~ubuntu20.04.1, 1.0.15-0~202204070351~ubuntu20.04.1), isc-dhcp-common:amd64 (4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.2, 4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3), dirmngr:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (101.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 102.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), gpgv:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), libmm-glib0:amd64 (1.16.6-2~20.04.1, 1.18.6-1~ubuntu20.04.1), libmbim-proxy:amd64 (1.24.8-1~20.04, 1.26.2-1~ubuntu20.04.1), libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.15, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16), firefox:amd64 (101.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 102.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), modemmanager:amd64 (1.16.6-2~20.04.1, 1.18.6-1~ubuntu20.04.1), libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.15, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16), libssl1.1:i386 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.15, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.16), gnupg:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), isc-dhcp-client:amd64 (4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.2, 4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3), libmbim-glib4:amd64 (1.24.8-1~20.04, 1.26.2-1~ubuntu20.04.1), gpg-agent:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), update-notifier:amd64 (3.192.30.10, 3.192.30.11), gpgconf:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2), gpgsm:amd64 (2.2.19-3ubuntu2.1, 2.2.19-3ubuntu2.2)
End-Date: 2022-07-06  15:28:55
```

For the example, I am showing the issue using hciconfig (instead of PyBluez), where the same scenario occurs.
Using hciconfig, we can see that the connection is never established, and the same is confirmed by btmon, where I see the events generated by Bluetooth.

```
$ sudo hcitool lecc --random 04:42:1A:57:16:91
Could not create connection: Connection timed out
```

I wanted to downgrade the updated software, but there are too many dependencies, and I'm afraid it would break the system.

Here is more information that might be relevant:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0827]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10) 


script /tmp/bluetooth.txt
    Script started, file is /tmp/bluetooth.txt
    marko@marko-Lenovo-Y520-15IKBN:/$ bluetoothd -d -n
    bluetoothd[16987]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
    bluetoothd[16987]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
    bluetoothd[16987]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DiscoverableTimeout” in group “General”
    bluetoothd[16987]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “AlwaysPairable” in group “General”
    bluetoothd[16987]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “PairableTimeout” in group “General”
    bluetoothd[16987]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Privacy” in group “General”
    bluetoothd[16987]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Name” in group “General”
    bluetoothd[16987]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “Class” in group “General”
    bluetoothd[16987]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “DeviceID” in group “General”
    bluetoothd[16987]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key “ReverseServiceDiscovery” in group “General”
    bluetoothd[16987]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
    bluetoothd[16987]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
    bluetoothd[16987]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have group “GATT”
    D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.131" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file
    bluetoothd[16987]: Unable to get on D-Bus
```

The connection can not be established neither from the machine's default Bluetooth adapter towards the external one, neither between the two external Bluetooth adapters. The external Bluetooth adapters are 5.0, and the adapter in the machine has the 4.2 Bluetooth version.

Bluetooth by itself works fine (I can connect to my phone, send files, audio is giving me troubles, but I don't know is that related to this) , however, I'm doing a research project on Bluetooth, and I'm using PyBluez to interact with the Bluetooth adapters (execute commands, listen for events etc.). Nothing besides connection seems to be impacted by the update.

Anyone has an idea how to troubleshoot this, or what might be the issue?
I'm not that familiar with the OS.